# Powershell Get-Random AND Rename-Item

Tags: powershell

I am attempling to rename all files in a folder to a random number.  Currently they have the date in each file name which does not help.

Here is my simple script:

```
$path = "C:\temp\photos\"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path

Foreach ($file in $files) {
$random = Get-Random
$file | Rename-Item -NewName {$Random + $_.extension}
}
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is 
no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.
At line:7 char:22
+ Rename-Item -NewName {$Random + $_.extension}
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may use parenthesis instead of curly braces. You may also notice that it is possible that you get a particular random number more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment by Olaf and with small adjustments:

```powershell
$path = "C:\temp\photos"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path
ForEach ($file in $files) {
  $random = Get-Random
  Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName ($random + $file.Extension)
}
```

However, you could probably make it a little shorter:

```powershell
$files = Get-Item -Path "C:\temp\photos\*"
ForEach ($file in $files) {
  Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName ([String]$(Get-Random) + $file.Extension)
}
```

No code has been included to prevent duplicate random names being generated, *which is outside of the scope of your question*.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if the random number is made to be a string, assuming get-childitem returns any results.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path 

Foreach ($file in $files) {
  $random = Get-Random
  $file | Rename-Item -NewName {"$Random" + $_.extension} -whatif
}

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item:        C:\Users\admin\file1.jpg 
Destination:  C:\Users\admin\1968532966.jpg".
```

Or as one pipeline:

```
(get-childitem $path) | rename-item -newname { "$(get-random)" + $_.extension} -whatif
```