# powershell-get-random-and-rename of everything under that directory including all files under a sub directory

Tags: powershell, file, rename

I'm trying to rename all the files in a directory AS WELL AS ANY files in any sub directory under that directory. I have lots of files named `filename1.JPG, filename2.JPG,filename3.JPG`... etc.. in order to combine all the files that currently are under different directory names INTO a single directory I need each file to have it's unique name.

I can get the PowerShell script to work if I go into every folder and run this command under power shell .. THIS DOES WORK but I need every file under every directory renamed.

`(get-childitem $path) | rename-item -newname { "$(get-random)" + $_.extension}`
( [Powershell Get-Random AND Rename-Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542103/powershell-get-random-and-rename-item#) )
I've tried to use the -Recurse option and it does seem to work if I simulate the command using the - whatif command.
`(get-childitem $path -Recurse) | rename-item -newname { "$(get-random)" + $_.extension} -whatif`

BUT when I remove the `-whatif`, it fails with a error message...

```
rename-item : Cannot rename because item at
'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\e0145817\Pictures\scanned\aug1\1124339616.XSM\00000002.JPG' does not
exist.
At line:1 char:34
+ ... th -Recurse) | rename-item -newname { "$(get-random)" + $_.extension}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

FYI... the `1124339616.XSM` in `C:\Users\e0145817\Pictures\scanned\aug1\1124339616.XSM\00000002.JPG` IS the NAME OF the FOLDER all the JPG files sit in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend using the `-File` switch on your `Get-ChildItem` command to ensure you are only renaming files.  If you rename a directory after it has been read into memory, memory won't contain the new directory name if your process continues to search within that directory.

Comment: That did it! (get-childitem -File -Recurse $path) | rename-item -newname { "$(get-random)" + $_.extension}